# Error for installing the OpenCV on raspberry (Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed ...)

Tags: software-installation, opencv

Based of [this post](https://howchoo.com/pi/install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi), I have tried to install the below package at first step:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install cmake pkg-config build-essential git
sudo apt install libwebp-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev libv4l-dev libavformat-dev  
sudo apt install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libdc1394-22-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libavcodec-dev 
sudo apt install libtiff-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libswscale-dev
sudo apt install libhdf5-dev libhdf5-103
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev libqtwebkit4 libqt4-test libqtgui4 python3-pyqt5
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-testresources python3-numpy
```

but, I have get below error for installing the OpenCV by the `pip install tqdm opencv-python imutils dlib imageio`command ([reference](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorchiefs/dl_book/blob/master/chapter_06/nb_ch06_05.ipynb#scrollTo=yGWVp5-AYFFV)) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install tqdm opencv-python imutils dlib imageio #-y
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/ec/f8ff3ccfc4e59ce619a66a0bf29dc3b49c2e8c07de29d572e191c006eaa2/tqdm-4.61.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a1/d6/8422797e35f8814b1d9842530566a949d9b5850a466321a6c1d5a99055ee/opencv-python-4.3.0.38.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-C24u7o/opencv-python/setup.py", line 448, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-C24u7o/opencv-python/setup.py", line 99, in main
        % {"ext": re.escape(sysconfig.get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX"))}
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 210, in escape
        s = list(pattern)
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-C24u7o/opencv-python/
```

[image]

So, if possible, I asked here to have some comment for fixing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand why do you use such an error prone procedure. Just install **OpenCV** from the default repository:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python3-opencv
```

This fit best to the Raspberry Pi OS and should install without problems. For additional moduls look with:

```
rpi ~$ apt list '*opencv*'
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ingo, dose using the `sudo apt full-upgrade` use high memory space on raspberry and if yes, almost **how much space on the `SD Card` this commands needs**?

Comment: @sosa Using the shown commands is the recommended way to keep the Raspberry Pi OS up to date. If in doubt with storage space you can execute `sudo apt clean` at the end. This will just delete the downloaded and cached installation packages (not the installed programs). They will be downloaded again if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Pip for Python 2.7.

Use `python3 -m pip install ...` or `pip3 install ...`.